# Bash script: Comparing strings in inline array vs. array imported with mapfile

Tags: arrays, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, string-comparison

I have two arrays, one with a list of domains and another with a list of blacklisted domains, which I want to compare. The idea is that the script is going to do X if the domain isn't blacklisted.

The script works fine if I make an array like this:

```
    DOMAINS=(
    'domain1.no 443'
    'domain2.no 443'
    'domain3.no 443'
    'domain4.no 443'
    'domain5.no 443'
    )
    BLACKLIST=(
    'domain1.no'
    'domain3.no'
    'domain5.no'
    )
```

```
Output:
domain1.no is blacklisted
domain2.no is NOT blacklisted
domain3.no is blacklisted
domain4.no is NOT blacklisted
domain5.no is blacklisted
```

But if I create the arrays by importing domains from domains.txt/blacklist.txt with mapfile -t then the script doesn't work. Like this:

```
mapfile -t DOMAINS < domains.txt
mapfile -t BLACKLIST < blacklist.txt
```

```
domains.txt contents:
domain1.no 443
domain2.no 443
domain3.no 443
domain4.no 443
domain5.no 443

blacklist.txt contents:
domain1.no
domain3.no
domain5.no

Output:
domain1.no is NOT blacklisted
domain2.no is NOT blacklisted
domain3.no is NOT blacklisted
domain4.no is NOT blacklisted
domain5.no is blacklisted
```

This is the rest of the script:

```
function test_function ()
{
    host=$1
    is_blacklisted=0
    
    for domain in "${BLACKLIST[@]}"; do
        if [[ " $host " == *" $domain "* ]]; then
            is_blacklisted=1
        fi
    done
    
    if [ $is_blacklisted == 1 ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$host is blacklisted"
        
    elif [ $is_blacklisted == 0 ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$host is NOT blacklisted"
    fi
}

for domain in "${DOMAINS[@]}"; do
    test_function $domain
done
```

**My question is, what is the reason that the comparison doesn't work properly when using the mapfile array?**

I'm very, *very* new to bash scripting (and to this site), my code might not bee too good and obvious answers will probably not be so obvious to me!

'443' is added to the DOMAINS array for another script that checks SSL, which is why it's there but not used in this script. I wanted to use these .txt files so that I don't have to update each scripts array manually but instead I can update the .txt file.

If it matters, I'm using Ubuntu/WSL from Microsoft app store.

Comment: Do your text files use `\r\n` line endings? Check with `od -c blacklist.txt`

Comment: Considering the platform you mention, are you sure the `.txt` files are not contaminated by `\r` characters before each end of line? You would need to do something like `${line::-1}` if that was the case.

Comment: A slightly off-topic side note: Associative arrays (e.g. `declare -A somearray` for string values or `declare -Ai somearray` for integer values) will give you a constant (or “log *N*” in the worst case) blacklist checking complexity instead of a linear one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys! I checked using the command and each line ends with \r  \n. Is there an option to get these removed from the files, or do I have to use something like ${line::-1} like Andrej mentioned? (any place I can read more about this too?)

Comment: And how would I implement ${line::-1} ? I'm really new to this, so please excuse my stupid questions!

Comment: I just remembered I use EOL-conversion with Notepad++ when I create the script, and it worked to convert the txt files too. Thanks for mentioning the line endings, now I can finally continue :) If either of you could post an answer I can mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: @Steffenno For a variable, e.g. `line`, `"$line"` is the unmodified value, `"${line::-1}"` is the value without the last character, `"${line%$'\r'}"` is the value without a trailing `\r` *if one is present* and unmodified otherwise (which is more universal) and `"${line//$'\r'}"` would remove each and every `\r`, not only at the end. This (and much more) is described in the “Expansion” section of the Bash `man` page. It works for arrays too, so `"${lines[3]%$'\r'}"` expands to the element at index 3 without a tailing `\r`, `lines=("${lines[@]%$'\r'}")` transforms the whole array at once etc.

Comment: Thank you Andrej, great explanation! I'll keep it in mind moving forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the most likely issue was a `\r` character left at the end of each line. Here’s a possible solution that removes such `\r` characters. Also, it preprocesses the blacklist into an associative array for more efficient lookups.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

if (($# != 2)); then
  echo "Usage: ${0} <blacklist file> <domains file>"
  exit 1
fi

is_blacklisted() {
  (($# == 2))  # crash on wrong number of arguments
  local -nr linenum_map="$1"  # array passed by name reference
  local -ir linenum='linenum_map["$2"]'  # integer evaluation
  if ((linenum)); then
    printf '%s is blacklisted on line %d\n' "$2" "$((linenum))"
    return 1  # easier for callers than output parsing
  else
    printf '%s is NOT blacklisted\n' "$2"
  fi
}

readarray -t input < "$1"
declare -Ai blacklist
for i in "${!input[@]}"; do
  ((blacklist["${input[i]%$'\r'}"] = i + 1))  # domain without \r -> line
done

readarray -t input < "$2"
domains=("${input[@]% *}")  # remove everything after space (maybe also \r)
for domain in "${domains[@]}"; do
  is_blacklisted 'blacklist' "$domain" || :  # don't crash on error
done
```

It seems to work reasonably with the input examples provided:

```
$ /tmp/blacklist.sh /tmp/blacklist.txt /tmp/domains.txt
domain1.no is blacklisted on line 1
domain2.no is NOT blacklisted
domain3.no is blacklisted on line 2
domain4.no is NOT blacklisted
domain5.no is blacklisted on line 3
```